# Instance is overutilized. Consider switching to the machine type: g1-small

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a new f1 micro instance with Ubuntu 16.04. I haven't logged in yet as I have not figured out how to create the SSH key-pair yet. But after two days, the Dashboard now shows:

> Instance "xxx" is overutilized. Consider switching to the machine type: g1-small

Why is this happening? Isn't a f1 micro similar to an ec2 t1.nano?  I have a t1.nano running a Node.js web site (with nginx, pm2, etc) and my CPU credit has been consistently at the maximum of 150 during this period with only me as a test user.

I started the f1 micro to run the same Node application to see which is more cost-effective. The parameter that was cloudy to me was that unexplained "0.2 virtual CPU". Is 0.2 CPU virtually unuseable?  Would 0.5 (g1 small) be significantly better?

Answer (score 1):

To address your connection problems, perhaps temporarily until you figure out the manual key management, you might want to try SSH from the browser which is possible from the Cloud Platform console or use gcloud CLI to assist you.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance

Once you get access via the terminal I would run 'top' or 'ps'.

Example of using ps to find the top CPU users:

```
ps wwaxr -o pid,stat,%cpu,time,command | head -10
```

Example of running top to find the top memory users:

```
top -l 1 -o rsize | head -20
```

Google Cloud also offers a monitoring product called Stackdriver which would give you this information in the Cloud console but it requires an agent to be running on your VM.  See the getting started guide if this sounds like a good option for you.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp

Once you get access to the resource usage data you should be able to determine if 1) the VM isn't powerful enough to run your node.js server or 2) perhaps something else got started on the host unexpectedly and that's the source of your usage.

Comment: Are there actually any penalties to over-utilization in terms of cost?  Because if there are none, I'll just stick with what I have.

Comment: No penalties that I know of.  Good luck!